Python: Find and replace html tags, with an exception?
I have this test.html and I need to find all lines that starts with <p class="text_obisnuit"> and <p class="text_obisnuit2"> , and have <br> instead ofthe close tag </p>. So, I have to remove  and replace with </p> .
THE PROBLEM:
Everuthing works, except this. I have a linie only with <br><br> this line must be excluded from the find and replace list
    <!-- ARTICOL START -->
<div align="justify">
        <table width="552" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td><h1 class="den_articol" itemprop="name">Zbuciumul sufletelor tenace (II)</h1></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text_dreapta">On Aprilie 27, 2013, in <a href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/leadership-fx-intensive.html" title="Vezi toate articolele din Leadership FX-Intensive" class="external" rel="category tag">Leadership FX-Intensive</a>, by Neculai Fantanaru</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <p class="text_obisnuit"><span class="text_obisnuit2">Zbuciumul sufletelor tenace </span>eviden&#355;iaz&#259; tendin&#355;a de a transforma evolu&#355;ia &icirc;n involu&#355;ie, atunci c&#226;nd zbuciumul t&#259;u existen&#355;ial pare c&#259; &icirc;ncepe s&#259; se &icirc;n&#259;spreasc&#259;. Astfel se creeaz&#259; o adev&#259;rat&#259; degringolad&#259; &icirc;n careul tr&#259;irilor &#351;i g&#226;ndurilor sale, o adev&#259;rat&#259; lupt&#259; &icirc;ntre tine &#351;i propriul t&#259;u Ego.<br>
        </p>
        <p class="text_obisnuit">Dac&#259; vrei s&#259; &#351;tii care este nivelul de leadership la care te afli, dac&#259; vrei s&#259; &#351;tii &icirc;n ce categorie de lideri te &icirc;ncadrezi, atunci dezleag&#259; adev&#259;ratul &icirc;n&#355;eles din spatele acelor vagi derute care &icirc;i despart pe oameni de cele dou&#259; constante: &ldquo; <em>a fi</em> &rdquo; &#351;i &ldquo; <em>a nu fi</em> &rdquo;, f&#259;r&#259; s&#259; te pierzi tu &icirc;nsu&#355;i &icirc;ntr-o mare de &icirc;ndoial&#259;.</p>
        <br><br>
        <p class="text_obisnuit"><span class="text_obisnuit2">* Not&#259;:</span> &ldquo; <em><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780516/" target="_new">Flawless (2007)</a>&quot;</em></p>

        </div>
    <p align="justify" class="text_obisnuit style3">&nbsp;</p>
   
       <!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->

Python code:
import os
import regex as re

def process_file_content(content):
    lines = content.split('\n')
    processed_lines = []

    for line in lines:
        stripped_line = line.strip()

        # Păstrăm liniile cu <br><br> neschimbate
        if '<br><br>' in line:
            processed_lines.append(line)
            continue

        # Procesăm doar liniile care conțin taguri <p>
        if '<p class="text_obisnuit"' in line or '<p class="text_obisnuit2"' in line:
            # Înlocuim <br> la sfârșitul liniei cu </p>
            line = re.sub(r'(<p class="text_obisnuit2?">.*?)<br>\s*$', r'\1</p>', line)

            # Eliminăm spațiile inutile de la început
            line = re.sub(r'^\s*(<p class="text_obisnuit2?">)', r'\1', line)

            # Eliminăm </p> dublu
            line = re.sub(r'(<p class="text_obisnuit2?">.*?</p>)\s*</p>\s*', r'\1', line)

        processed_lines.append(line)

    content = '\n'.join(processed_lines)

    # Adăugăm spații între paragrafe
    content = re.sub(r'(</p>)\s*(<p class="text_obisnuit">)', r'\1\n\n\2', content)
    content = re.sub(r'(</p>)\s*(<p class="text_obisnuit2">)', r'\1\n\n\2', content)

    return content

def process_html_files(directory):
    excluded_files = [
        'aforisme-si-pareri-bine-slefuite-III.html',
        'aforisme-si-pareri-bine-slefuite-II.html',
        'aforisme-si-pareri-bine-slefuite.html',
        'cartea-cartilor.html',
        'cartea-creatiei.html',
        'cartea-de-nisip.html',
        'ganduri-din-colturile-memoriei-III.html',
        'imagini-din-muzeul-mitropolitan-iasi.html',
        'ganduri-din-colturile-memoriei-II.html',
        'ganduri-din-colturile-memoriei.html'
    ]

    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith('.html') and filename not in excluded_files:
            file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                content = file.read()

            processed_content = process_file_content(content)

            if content != processed_content:
                print(f"\nModificări în fișierul: {filename}")
                with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                    file.write(processed_content)

            # Verificăm dacă mai există linii cu <br><br> după procesare
            if '<br><br>' in processed_content:
                print(f"\nLinia <br><br> păstrată în fișierul: {filename}")

# Specificați directorul cu fișierele HTML
directory = r'd:\55'
process_html_files(directory)

Face bine toate schimbarile, in afara de cazul ca linia care contine doar <br><br> este inlocuita cu <p class="text_obisnuit"></p> . Ei bine, trebuie o clauda prin care linia care contine doar <br><br> sa nu fie inclusa in celelalte Find and Replace.

    <!-- ARTICOL START -->
<div align="justify">
        <table width="552" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td><h1 class="den_articol" itemprop="name">Zbuciumul sufletelor tenace (II)</h1></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text_dreapta">On Aprilie 27, 2013, in <a href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/leadership-fx-intensive.html" title="Vezi toate articolele din Leadership FX-Intensive" class="external" rel="category tag">Leadership FX-Intensive</a>, by Neculai Fantanaru</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
<p class="text_obisnuit"><span class="text_obisnuit2">Zbuciumul sufletelor tenace </span>eviden&#355;iaz&#259; tendin&#355;a de a transforma evolu&#355;ia &icirc;n involu&#355;ie, atunci c&#226;nd zbuciumul t&#259;u existen&#355;ial pare c&#259; &icirc;ncepe s&#259; se &icirc;n&#259;spreasc&#259;. Astfel se creeaz&#259; o adev&#259;rat&#259; degringolad&#259; &icirc;n careul tr&#259;irilor &#351;i g&#226;ndurilor sale, o adev&#259;rat&#259; lupt&#259; &icirc;ntre tine &#351;i propriul t&#259;u Ego.</p>

<p class="text_obisnuit">Dac&#259; vrei s&#259; &#351;tii care este nivelul de leadership la care te afli, dac&#259; vrei s&#259; &#351;tii &icirc;n ce categorie de lideri te &icirc;ncadrezi, atunci dezleag&#259; adev&#259;ratul &icirc;n&#355;eles din spatele acelor vagi derute care &icirc;i despart pe oameni de cele dou&#259; constante: &ldquo; <em>a fi</em> &rdquo; &#351;i &ldquo; <em>a nu fi</em> &rdquo;, f&#259;r&#259; s&#259; te pierzi tu &icirc;nsu&#355;i &icirc;ntr-o mare de &icirc;ndoial&#259;.</p>

<p class="text_obisnuit"></p>

<p class="text_obisnuit"><span class="text_obisnuit2">* Not&#259;:</span> &ldquo; <em><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780516/" target="_new">Flawless (2007)</a>&quot;</em></p>

        </div>
    <p align="justify" class="text_obisnuit style3">&nbsp;</p>
   
       <!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->

This must be the output:
    <!-- ARTICOL START -->
<div align="justify">
        <table width="552" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td><h1 class="den_articol" itemprop="name">Zbuciumul sufletelor tenace (II)</h1></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text_dreapta">On Aprilie 27, 2013, in <a href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/leadership-fx-intensive.html" title="Vezi toate articolele din Leadership FX-Intensive" class="external" rel="category tag">Leadership FX-Intensive</a>, by Neculai Fantanaru</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <p class="text_obisnuit"><span class="text_obisnuit2">Zbuciumul sufletelor tenace </span>eviden&#355;iaz&#259; tendin&#355;a de a transforma evolu&#355;ia &icirc;n involu&#355;ie, atunci c&#226;nd zbuciumul t&#259;u existen&#355;ial pare c&#259; &icirc;ncepe s&#259; se &icirc;n&#259;spreasc&#259;. Astfel se creeaz&#259; o adev&#259;rat&#259; degringolad&#259; &icirc;n careul tr&#259;irilor &#351;i g&#226;ndurilor sale, o adev&#259;rat&#259; lupt&#259; &icirc;ntre tine &#351;i propriul t&#259;u Ego.</p>
        <p class="text_obisnuit">Dac&#259; vrei s&#259; &#351;tii care este nivelul de leadership la care te afli, dac&#259; vrei s&#259; &#351;tii &icirc;n ce categorie de lideri te &icirc;ncadrezi, atunci dezleag&#259; adev&#259;ratul &icirc;n&#355;eles din spatele acelor vagi derute care &icirc;i despart pe oameni de cele dou&#259; constante: &ldquo; <em>a fi</em> &rdquo; &#351;i &ldquo; <em>a nu fi</em> &rdquo;, f&#259;r&#259; s&#259; te pierzi tu &icirc;nsu&#355;i &icirc;ntr-o mare de &icirc;ndoial&#259;.</p>
        <br><br>
        <p class="text_obisnuit"><span class="text_obisnuit2">* Not&#259;:</span> &ldquo; <em><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780516/" target="_new">Flawless (2007)</a>&quot;</em></p>

        </div>
    <p align="justify" class="text_obisnuit style3">&nbsp;</p>
   
       <!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->


Solved:
import os
import regex as re

def process_file_content(content):
    lines = content.split('\n')
    processed_lines = []

    for line in lines:
        # Păstrăm spațiile inițiale ale fiecărei linii
        leading_spaces = re.match(r'^\s*', line).group()

        stripped_line = line.strip()

        # Păstrăm liniile cu <br><br> neschimbate
        if '<br><br>' in stripped_line:
            processed_lines.append(line)
            continue

        # Procesăm doar liniile care conțin taguri <p>
        if '<p class="text_obisnuit"' in stripped_line or '<p class="text_obisnuit2"' in stripped_line:
            # Înlocuim <br> la sfârșitul liniei cu </p>
            stripped_line = re.sub(r'(<p class="text_obisnuit2?">.*?)<br>\s*$', r'\1</p>', stripped_line)

            # Eliminăm spațiile inutile de la început
            stripped_line = re.sub(r'^\s*(<p class="text_obisnuit2?">)', r'\1', stripped_line)

            # Eliminăm </p> dublu
            stripped_line = re.sub(r'(<p class="text_obisnuit2?">.*?</p>)\s*</p>\s*', r'\1', stripped_line)

        # Adăugăm spațiile inițiale înapoi
        processed_lines.append(leading_spaces + stripped_line)

    content = '\n'.join(processed_lines)

    # Adăugăm spații între paragrafe
    # content = re.sub(r'(</p>)\s*(<p class="text_obisnuit">)', r'\1\n\n\2', content)
    # content = re.sub(r'(</p>)\s*(<p class="text_obisnuit2">)', r'\1\n\n\2', content)

    # Eliminăm liniile care conțin doar </p>
    content = re.sub(r'^\s*</p>\s*$', '', content, flags=re.MULTILINE)

    return content

def process_html_files(directory):
    excluded_files = [
        'aforisme-si-pareri-bine-slefuite-III.html',
        'aforisme-si-pareri-bine-slefuite-II.html',
        'aforisme-si-pareri-bine-slefuite.html',
        'cartea-cartilor.html',
        'cartea-creatiei.html',
        'cartea-de-nisip.html',
        'ganduri-din-colturile-memoriei-III.html',
        'imagini-din-muzeul-mitropolitan-iasi.html',
        'ganduri-din-colturile-memoriei-II.html',
        'ganduri-din-colturile-memoriei.html'
    ]

    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith('.html') and filename not in excluded_files:
            file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                content = file.read()

            processed_content = process_file_content(content)

            if content != processed_content:
                print(f"\nModificări în fișierul: {filename}")
                with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                    file.write(processed_content)

            # Verificăm dacă mai există linii cu <br><br> după procesare
            if '<br><br>' in processed_content:
                print(f"\nLinia <br><br> păstrată în fișierul: {filename}")

# Specificați directorul cu fișierele HTML
directory = r'd:\55'
process_html_files(directory)

